# ios understand the SIGABRT in my block

Tags: ios, sigabrt

I have a block that fires once my image is downloaded. the `data` coming in from the block is the image. I'm not sure why I'm getting a SIGABRT though. This works fine on the first load, but when I come back to this same spot I always crash out the second time.

Everything you would want to see should be in the bottom left and printed out on the bottom right in the following order: `data`, `ptr`, `ptr`->`imageImg`

[image]

** EDIT **

I forgot to add the stack dump as well

```
2012-06-21 15:52:59.119 iPhone App[25327:16a03] -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10e41b80
2012-06-21 15:52:59.120 iPhone App[25327:16a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10e41b80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c35022 0x37dccd6 0x1c36cbd 0x1b9bed0 0x1b9bcb2 0x68e97a 0x5612c8 0x56102b 0x1be82 0x2afbc 0x46ad330 0x46af509 0x1b6c803 0x1b6bd84 0x1b6bc9b 0x1dc77d8 0x1dc788a 0x546626 0x28704 0x20d5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the _text_ of the stackdump and the program; images are impossible to search -- and I find your colors too garish to fight through.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what was at `0x10e41b80`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying not to pull my hair out, I finally figured it out.

## the situation

I have a caching system to cache a file on download and then send the stored version back to my callback. For some reason I was trying to save to a filepath that had a question mark (and other symbols) in it which apparently would NOT let ios save the file to the device *note xcode nor the device ever warned me that the file wasn't be saved either. However the record keeping system was showing that everything was working fine which meant the data sent back was empty NSData.

## the solution

I made sure that my filepath had NO symbols in it when saving offline data and viola.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `length` on `UIImage`, but `UIImage` doesn't have a method called `length`.

Comment: note: `imageWithData` and NSData has `length` on it. However, your comment has led me to believe that the data object is not actually `NSData`, but rather a `UIImage`. If it is, you shall still win the prize!